# Opening link in new window

Tags: html

I am working on a CMS site that uses dynamic navigation. There is one link on the site that I would like to be able to open in a new window. However, since this is a dynamic environment I can't add the standard, target="_blank" to the link. so how can i open the link in new window without using jquery ?

Comment: You are going to need to clarify what you mean by "dynamic navigation" and why that prevents you from using _blank

Comment: I don't entirely understand what you mean by "dynamic environment". Can you use Javascript at all? Do those links have identifiers? Why is JQuery out of the question?

Comment: that link may be external link which need to open in new window or may be internal link which needs to be open in same window

Comment: If you mean you are developing database-driven navigation you may need a column to indicate the target of the link.

Are entering data into an existing CMS with no means of updating the code?

Answer (score 0):

$("#linkid").attr("target", "_blank");

Or to target by a css style $(".linkclass")

Comment: That's how I would do it too, however he doesn't seem to want to use JQuery for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on the link and press "Open in new Window/Tab"

Seriously, you shouldn't overwrite the default behavior of the browser nor force the user to open a link in a new window. If the user want to open the link in a new window he already know how to do it (by selecting the entry in the popup menu, or even use a mouse gesture). But opening a link in the same window if the link is "forced" to open in a new window (with `target="_blank"`) is much more difficult, specially if there is javascript involved (I really hate links like `javascript:showDetails('12453563');`)

Answer (score 0):

For all links on the page without jQuery but with Javascript:

```
links=document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
    links[i].target="_blank";
}
```

For just the link that you want, if it is giving a unique ID:

```
link=document.getElementByID("link_id");
link.target="_blank";
```

For the link you want with no ID provided, if you know the URL:

```
links=document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
    if(links[i].href = "http://the/url/you/are/targeting") {
        links[i].target="_blank";
     }
}
```

For the link you want with no idea provided, if there's a given class associated with it:

```
links=document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
    if(links[i].className = "blankLinkClass") {
        links[i].target="_blank";
     }
}
```